# How to retrieve any kind of data from Bloomberg professional

Tags: api, bloomberg

I want to download the earning calls for many companies in Bloomberg. 
I couldn't find a lot of information about the Bloomberg API on the internet, so before getting deep into it, I would like to know if you think that it is possible to automate this task or if Bloomberg doesn't allow it.
Also I heard about the "sendkeys" function, do you think that I can use it to retreive earning calls ?

Comment: earning calls as in the audio/video of the earning presentation or just the figures? When you say Bloomberg API, do you mean the API linked to a Bloomberg terminal to which you subscribe?

Comment: Can this info be accessed via FLDS<GO> function on the Professional Terminal? If so, you can use API v3: http://www.openbloomberg.com/files/2012/03/blpapi-developers-guide.pdf